# Is the component wise convergence limit of a sequence defined on an infinite dimensional space the same as its uniform convergence limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, pointwise-convergence

Consider a sequence $(\bar{x_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined on an infinite dimensional space, with e.g the product topology defined on that space. Is it then true that (omitting the ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$ subscript):

> $(\bar{x_n}) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} x$ in the product topology $\iff$ for each component we have $(\bar{x_n}_j) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} (\bar{x_j})$, where $j$ corresponds to the dimension/component?

Is this equivalence true? If so, I am assuming it is a special case for when the product topology is defined on the infinite dimensional space?

My confusion really is when can one check what a sequence (defined on an infinite dimensional space) converges to by simply looking at the convergence component wise? Because for finite dimensional spaces I am aware that the  pointwise convergence limit (i.e component wise convergence limit) will be the same as the uniform convergence limit on the product space. But for infinite dimensional spaces, as [http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L17.html](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/analysis/Lectures/L17.html) points out with a good example, this is generally not possible. Hence, back to the above statement, is it true? Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Vector spaces do not have, in general, « components subspaces ».

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but the product topology is always the topology of pointwise convergence